# Results based on location

Tags: node.js, google-maps, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to make it so that my Google Assistant Chat Bot can request to know the users location and then tell them the closest Doctors surgery for example. I don't want it so that the user views the map, I just want it so that the bot comes back and says "The nearest doctors surgery to you is the Theatre Royal Surgery. It's 10 miles from your location."

Is there a way of doing this? If so some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want to take a look at the [user information helper](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information), which will ask the user if it can get their location (either their current location if asked on a mobile device, or the location they have set if using a Google Home or similar device) and share it with your Action.

If you are using the actions-on-google library, this is done using the Permission helper, and your code might look something like

```
app.intent('ask_for_permissions_detailed', (conv) => {
  // Choose one or more supported permissions to request:
  // NAME, DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION, DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION
  const options = {
    context: 'To address you by name and know your location',
    // Ask for more than one permission. User can authorize all or none.
    permissions: ['NAME', 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'],
  };
  conv.ask(new Permission(options));
});
```

Using the dialogflow-fulfillment library is similar.

If you're using the multivocal library, you want the `Session/Location` environment to be set, so you could require that for any Intents you need it for and it will be requested with something like

```
  "Local": {
    "und": {
      "Requirements": {
        "Intent.compute.distance": "Session/Location"
      }
    }
  }
```

You can then use Maps' [Place Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) to give it the location and search terms for what you're looking for to get a list of nearby results and send them back.

Comment: Great and how do I use that with Google maps?

Comment: Added link to the Place Search API.